# How to limit the number of outgoing connections for Netty client?

Tags: java, netty

Is there a way to limit (or just get) the number of outgoing connections in netty library (version 4.x)?

There is `nThreads` option in `NioEventLoopGroup` which is equal to `numberOfCpuCores * 2`, but each thread uses a `Selector` for many connections.

P.S. This is how requests are made.

```
Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
b.group(eventLoopGroup)
     .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
     .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
     .handler(new MyHandler());    
ChannelFuture cf = b.connect(host, port);
cf.addListener(new MyConnectionListener());
```

Comment: Maybe [UniqueIpFilter](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/ipfilter/UniqueIpFilter.html) can help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement your own ChannelOutboundHandler. Use `Semaphore` to control the connection number. When `connect` to acquire and when `disconnect`, `close` and `exceptionCaught` to release. Note that avoid to release repeatedly to make `Semaphore` to be negative.

Comment: tx, i'll give it a try this week

Answer (score 0):

I think this is unrelated to netty.  You just need a channel counter and add it each time you create a channel.